# Jquery script like google image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking a script (example in web) like google images preview. I have attached an image what I am looking for

[image]

I have spend a time of looking such script / example but nothing. If someone know a name or a link please give it to me.

Comment: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/03/jquery-slider.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a script but it's not exactly like Google Image's but has the same functionality. The script is free and is coded in HTML with CSS and JavaScript.

[image]

[Click here to view the script](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/)